# Riot.js error while building, using Riotjs Webpack Starterkit

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I am trying to add a method to te existing tag, to be called when a button is clicked, i am getting this error while dev build.

https://github.com/wbkd/riotjs-startkit

ERROR in ./src/components/itemlist.tag
Module build failed: SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (15:15)
    });

```
addItem(e) {
    console.log('elo');
}

at Parser.pp.raise (C:\Users\Adam\Documents\test\riotjs-startkit-master\node_modules\babel\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\location.js:24:13)
at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\Users\Adam\Documents\test\riotjs-startkit-master\node_modules\babel\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\util.js:82:8)
at Parser.pp.semicolon (C:\Users\Adam\Documents\test\riotjs-startkit-master\node_modules\babel\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\util.js:69:81)
at Parser.pp.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\Adam\Documents\test\riotjs-startkit-master\node_modules\babel\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\statement.js:427:8)
at Parser.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\Adam\Documents\test\riotjs-startkit-master\node_modules\babel\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\plugins\flow.js:676:20)
at Parser.pp.parseStatement (C:\Users\Adam\Documents\test\riotjs-startkit-master\node_modules\babel\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\statement.js:142:21)
at Parser.parseStatement (C:\Users\Adam\Documents\test\riotjs-startkit-master\node_modules\babel\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\plugins\flow.js:655:22)
at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (C:\Users\Adam\Documents\test\riotjs-startkit-master\node_modules\babel\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\statement.js:30:21)
at Parser.parse (C:\Users\Adam\Documents\test\riotjs-startkit-master\node_modules\babel\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\index.js:70:17)
at Object.parse (C:\Users\Adam\Documents\test\riotjs-startkit-master\node_modules\babel\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:45:50)
```

@ ./src/pages/home.tag 5:0-37

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the parser (babylon) used by webpack which doesn't accepts this syntax. Try the classic syntax instead `this.addItem = function() { /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that startkit use webpack and babel to transpile from es6. 
The syntax that you are using is provided by Riot, is not real es6.

So if you are transpiling from es6 use the es6 syntax, because the Riot.js syntax will not work.

```
this.addItem = (e) => {
    console.log('elo');
}
```

If not you can use js syntax

```
this.addItem = function(s) {
    console.log('elo');
}
```

or also you can use the es6-like syntax provided by Riot.js

```
addItem(e) {
    console.log('elo');
}
```